# Multiple navigation.push same screen always go to the last of the list

Tags: react-native, navigation, screen, multiple-screens

I have a screen to display news articles. In a news there can be reference to other articles. On clicking on the reference i go to another news detail screen which display the new articles.
If have only one reference to another article, it works fine, even go back.
But if i have more reference, i always go to the last news article and not to the specific news article i am clicking on. The reference is the "id" of the article, pass via the param of a navigation.push, inside a .
Why is it always the last news id that is used ? I put the id (infNum) in the  area, and it references the correct id of each article, but it seems that the param idNews is always the last infNum.
Here is my code :
'''

```
{news.results.texte.map((content, index) => {
        if(content.substring(0,6) === '_Info_') {
            {
            finNum = content.indexOf("_T_");
            finLien = content.indexOf("_/Info_");
            infNum = content.substring(6,finNum);
            txtLien = content.substring(finNum+3,finLien)
            }
            //console.log(finNum," ",finLien," ",infNum," ",txtLien)
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.txtLien}
                    key={infNum}
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.push("NewsDetail", {idNews:infNum})}
                    }
                >
                    <Text>{txtLien}-{infNum}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        } else {
            return (
              <Text style={styles.description_text} key={index}>{content}</Text>
            )
        }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Basic Javascript. The variable 'infNum' as it is not declared with the 'var' keyword is considered as global and so takes the last value given. I just put 'var infNum = content.substring ....' and it works well